# Laravel - Simulating a process but not modifying original models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need to somehow isolate a scope or a class to not modify the Eloquent models if not told otherwise:

I have a bunch of accounts and services. Each account has a bunch of relations (rules and restrictions) what help to determine for what it can be used to pay for and how.

**What I need to do now is simulate the purchase of a bunch of services or service combinations.**

1. So if I have X accounts and Y services then for every simulation to query/refresh the relations again I would have to make too many requests so that's not an option.

   ```
   new Purchase($accounts, $services); 
   new Purchase($accounts, $otherServices);
   ...
   ```
2. Then next logical step was to load in all the relations and then simulate the purchase process. Except when I'm done simulating or the first service then for the next purchase all the values have already been changed.

**Here's a simplified version of my problem:**

```
    function doSomething($user)
    {
        $user->doneSomething = true;
    }

    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->doneSomething = false;

    doSomething($user);

    dd($user->doneSomething); // true -- But  this one time I want it to be false
```

3. Okay so then I have to reset the models after my function. This would probably be easier if I had used the all the rules as they came from the database.

   ```
   $account->setRawAttributes($account->getOriginal())
   ```

But now I also want to use the same function to simulate some cases where I have modified the accounts and rules prior to the function.

---

I have also thought about converting everything to arrays with `getAtributes()` `getRelations()` and then working with those. But then I lose the option to use all the model functions.

Also I am aware of the Eloquent Model `replicate()` function. But this seems cumbersome and eventually I also need to call save on the calculated and updated rows;

---

And finally to illustrate the problem once more I need to add a big bubble/isolated scope around a function so whatever Eloquent models are passed in as arguments will remain the same.

```
   // Purchse.php 

    public function calculate()
    {
        foreach($this->services as &$service)
            foreach($this->accounts as &$account)
                ...
    }

    // Calling the purchase:

    isolateEverything(function () {
        $purchase = new Purchase($accounts, $services);
        $result = $purchase->calculate();
    });
```

One way would be store and replace before the calculation function. But seems like a lot of useless code.

Another would be to somehow isolate the function from the outside world.

What's the best way of achieving all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found some *magic* methods that can help me out. They are still to be fully tested out but my first simple experiment shows that this might work.

I think I can use [syncOriginal()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_syncOriginal) to store the values as originals

```
    public function syncOriginal()
    {
        $this->original = $this->attributes;

        return $this;
    }
```

And then after I have done a calculation and need to reset I can call [setRawAttributes()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setRawAttributes) together with [getOriginal()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal)

```
    $account->setRawAttributes($account->getOriginal());
```

And in case I don't want to change the original attributes I can create similar methods like `syncBackup()` and `getBackup()`.

Seems like in the end all I needed was to find a normal place to store the backup values.

> *That feeling when you're searching for a solution so long that eventually you create a question on SO and soon after that you find a solution.*

**Edit:** Here's what I currently made and seems to work for me.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class BaseModel extends Model {

    private $backup = array();

    public function createBackup()
    {
        $this->backup = $this->attributes;

        foreach ($this->getRelations() as $relation => $value) 
        {
            if($value instanceof self)
            {
                $value->createBackup();
            }
        }
    }

    public function popBackup()
    {
        $this->setRawAttributes($this->backup);

        foreach ($this->getRelations() as $relation => $value) 
        {
            if($value instanceof self)
            {
                $value->popBackup();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From here it is also possible to create array of backups and start poping them one by one if needed. And this could also probably be made as a trait.